# GCP KMS UI Not Displaying All Keys

Tags: google-cloud-kms

I have a keyring in KMS which has about 3500 keys in it. When I go to look at them in the Google Cloud console I can only see up to 1000 of them. This would be understandable if only 1000 were loaded for the UI, but the search also seems capped at 1000. It seems that the UI only fetches 1000 keys max, with no option to fetch any more.

I have the scenario now where I cannot access any newly created keys in this keyring via the console, even if I explicitly search for them by ID, because they exist beyond this (first?) 1000 keys. Is there a way of searching all the keys in my keyring or is this a limitation of cloud console?

[image]

Comment: This is a long-standing and known issue with Cloud KMS in the UI. You need to use the API to see the additional keys.

Comment: Any plans to add the capability to see more?

Comment: There are a number of upcoming improvements to the KMS UI.

Comment: @sethvargo, could it be possible for you to post your comment as an answer, for community benefit please?

Answer (score 0):

“In order to be able to see the additional keys, the user was suggested to use the API, as the behavior described by the user has been a Cloud KMS’ known issue for a long time. Plus, the user was asked to wait for some KMS UI’s upcoming improvements” - @sethvargo